# how to find needed udev rules for streamdeck (hid)

Tags: linux, udev, hid

I got myself streamdeck to play with. No support for linux by company, but there is streamdeck-ui written in python, which kinda works (but kinda does not work, so I'd like to use something else, potentially my own). Writing app will be relatively easy, hard part is using existing hid libraries / communicating with device.  Streamdeck-ui asks for udev rules having format:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fd9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0060", TAG+="uaccess"

I can substitute correct idVendor,idProduct with actual value printed by lsusb, that's fine. streamdeck-ui "works as expected". I'd like to move on, but if I try to connect to device using any java (sorry) hid library, I cannot open it, because of access issues. If I ran same code as root(yuck), it works. Similarly as streamdeck-ui behaved without udev rules; it worked under root, but otherwise it did not. Meaning, that java hid libraries probably needs some other / some more rules than what python needs.

I also saw following template being recommended:

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fd9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0080", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

which does not work either for me, and I saw somewhere that MODE should not be used, and TAG is correct way.

Yes, I did reload rules and even reboot the machine without any luck. Noone else is using the device. Meaning there is probably something missing. I have to yet read the sources of streamdeck-ui to find out what they are doing, but can someone advice how to debug udev? How to find out WHY was access rejected by OS and what can be done to allow it? It's probably some basic udev knowledge (I'm missing).

Comment: I was lucky with googling, this is working solution: `KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fd9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0080", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"`. But I have no idea how should I come up with that by myself. If you can suggest how this is solved, please do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the proper udev rules should be, but the HID device IDs can be obtained from this registry: https://usb-ids.gowdy.us/read/UD/0fd9.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).